# How to append ChildNodes of a xml documents into root of another (web services)?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, appendchild

I've created a `[WebMethod]` on ASP.NET Web Service which reads XML documents from different web services (ASP.NET and PHP services).

Once the documents are read, they are merged into a XML and returned.

The method can successfully read XML documents from each web service but when I try to append second XML into first one, I get `ArgumentException` and a message like this `The node to be inserted is from a different document context.` I can't find a problem, can it be something to do with the source of document? but then both document are exactly same (have same elements).

Why `ArgumentException`? What am I missing?

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument getRestaurants(String search_keywords)
{
  XmlDocument xmlDom1 = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDom1 = getRestaurantFromAspNetWS(search_keywords);

  XmlTextReader myXmlTextReader = 
  new XmlTextReader
  ("http://some-iss.green.com/username/search.php?s=" + search_keywords);

  XmlDocument xmlDom2 = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDom2.Load(myXmlTextReader);

  foreach (XmlElement xmlNode in xmlDom2.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
  {
     //trying to append childNodes of xmlDom2 into xmlDom1 
     //and this is where i get ArgumentException
     xmlDom1.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlNode);
  } 

  return xmlDom1;
}
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlDocument instead of LINQ to XML?

Comment: I would prefer using XmlDocument but am open to explore new ideas. Would you point out something to read? Can you see problem on the code above?

Comment: You should look at `XmlDocument.ImportNode`, but I would *strongly* urge you to look at LINQ to XML. It's a *vastly* better XML API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the node with importNode()
something like this:

```
xmlDom1.DocumentElement.importNode(xmlNode, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you write it like this?

```
public XElement getRestaurants(String search_keywords)
{
    XElement result = getRestaurantFromAspNetWS(search_keywords);

    XmlTextReader myXmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader
        ("http://some-iss.green.com/username/search.php?s=" + search_keywords);

    XElement reader = XElement.Load(myXmlTextReader);
    foreach (XElement child in reader.Elements())
        result.Add(child);

    return result;
}
```

The real trick is getting your custom `getRestaurantFromAspNetWS` function to return a XElement instead of a XmlDocument, as you didn't provide us with that function, I can't help you there.